# moving files to their respective folders using bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have files in this format:

```
2022-03-5344-REQUEST.jpg
2022-03-5344-IMAGE.jpg
2022-03-5344-00imgtest.jpg
2022-03-5344-anotherone.JPG
2022-03-5343-kdijffj.JPG
2022-03-5343-zslkjfs.jpg
2022-03-5343-myimage-2010.jpg
2022-03-5343-anotherone.png
2022-03-5342-ebee5654.jpeg
2022-03-5342-dec.jpg
2022-03-5341-att.jpg
2022-03-5341-timephoto_december.jpeg
....
```

about 13k images like these.

I want to create folders like:

```
2022-03-5344/
2022-03-5343/
2022-03-5342/
2022-03-5341/
....
```

I started manually moving them like:

```
mkdir name
mv name-* name/
```

But of course I'm not gonna repeat this process for 13k files.

So I want to do this using bash scripting, and since I am new to bash, and I am working on a **production** environment, I want to play it safe, but it doesn't give me my results. This is what I did so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

name = $1

mkdir "$name"

mv "${name}-*" $name/
```

and all I can do is: `./move.sh name` for every folder, I didn't know how to automate this using loops.

Comment: `name = $1` tries to execute a program named _name_. To set the variable, you have to use `name=$1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` and a regex. I assume that the files are all in the current directory.

```
for name in *; do
  if [[ "$name" =~ (^....-..-....)- ]]; then
    dir="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";    # dir contains 2022-03-5344, e.g.
    echo mkdir -p "$dir" || exit 1;
    echo mv -v "$name" "$dir";
  fi;
done
```

If output looks okay, remove both `echo`.

Comment: nitpick: some `;` seem unnecessary(?)

Comment: @ErikMD: Thank you. I kept this so it would be easier to reformat all the code into a single line if necessary.

Comment: I don't quite understand the code I'm looking at here. Do I keep name = $1 in my bash file? How can the code know what i'm talking about when I execute the script? And is there a way I can do a for loop so it goes through all the files at onces?

Comment: Oh I understand now! I thought you meant remove the whole echo lines, while you meant only the echo words. I tried it, and worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I also have the same question about PostgreSQL, I want to modify some paths of these files that are in a PostgreSQL database and I want to do an SQL query to automate that. I'll post the link here if admins permit.

Comment: A related question in SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72428007/bulk-updating-with-a-condition-in-sql-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
xargs -i sh -c 'mkdir -p {}; mv {}-* {}' < <(ls *-*-*-*|awk -F- -vOFS=- '{print $1,$2,$3}'|uniq)
```

Or:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*-*-*-*" | \
awk -F- -vOFS=- '{print $1,$2,$3}' | \
sort -u | \
xargs -i sh -c 'mkdir -p {}; mv {}-* {}'
```

Or find with regex:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`

```
$ cat awk.script
/^[[:digit:]-]/ && ! a[$1]++ {
    dir=$1
} /^[[:digit:]-]/ {
    system("sudo mkdir " dir )
    system("sudo mv " $0" "dir"/"$0)
}
```

To call the script and use for your purposes;

```
$ awk -F"-([0-9]+)?[[:alpha:]]+.*" -f awk.script <(ls)
```

You will see some errors such as;

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘2022-03-5341’: File exists
```

after the initial dir has been created, you can safely ignore these as the dir now exist.

The content of each directory will now have the relevant files

```
$ ls 2022-03-5344
2022-03-5344-00imgtest.jpg  2022-03-5344-IMAGE.jpg  2022-03-5344-REQUEST.jpg  2022-03-5344-anotherone.JPG
```