# Bulk updating with a condition in SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I recently made a change in my linux machine by organizing all the images into their respective folders, using a bash script (see answer and solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72427271/9999674):

I had about 13k images and they all start with a unique identifier, each identifier has many images. I decided to put all images with the same identifier in the same folder, named after the identified.

Now I have to update my database so it still points to the correct directory. I want to change the table from the output you saw above, to this:

[image]

Is there a way we can automate this? Maybe the equivalent of a bash script for SQL? Like an SQL function? or simply a very elaborate SQL query involving ifs and for loops?

**PS: Some of my rows already have this path/to/newly_created_folder/file.ext so I want the query to ignore this so it doesn't replace it again.**

Comment: Show your table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement), your Postgres version, some sample rows, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   id   INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,path VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test(id,path) VALUES 
(1,'path/to/2022-05-1200-something.jpg'),
(2,'path/to/2022-05-1200-somethingelse.jpg'),
(3,'path/to/2022-05-1200-anotherone.JPG'),
(4,'path/to/2022-05-1201-newfile.jpeg'),
(5,'path/to/2022-05-1201-anothernewfile.png'),
(6,'path/to/2022-05-1202-completelydiffernetone.PNO');
```

you need using multiple use of `split_part` and `concat`

```
SELECT id,concat(split_part(path, '/', 1),'/'
     , split_part(path, '/', 2),'/'
     , concat(split_part(split_part(path, '/', 3), '-', 1) ,'-'
     , split_part(path, '-', 2) ,'-'
     , split_part(path, '-', 3)),'/'
       , split_part(path, '/', 3)) AS path
FROM   test;
```

for creating function use following query

```
Create function p2(input VARCHAR(100))  
returns VARCHAR(100)
language plpgsql  
as  
$$  
Declare  
    output VARCHAR(100);  
Begin  
    SELECT concat(split_part(input, '/', 1),'/'
    , split_part(input, '/', 2),'/'
    , concat(split_part(split_part(input, '/', 3), '-', 1) ,'-'
    , split_part(input, '-', 2) ,'-'
    , split_part(input, '-', 3)),'/'
    , split_part(input, '/', 3))
    into output; 
    return output;
End;  
$$;
```

after creating function,use following query

```
select id,path,p2(path) from test
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0d924010dcd3e76f9d658709fe560ace)

Comment: How can I do this for 13000 rows in 3 tables? Is there any way we can use PL/SQL to create a procedure or function that does this?

Comment: I have add function that you need.

Comment: Did it worked in your issue?

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally did not go with this method since I am working directly on a production environment so I prefer doing this manually, it takes days but I'm updating the database per the client need.